# Получаю ошибку 502 bad gateway nginx когда загружаю тяжелые файлы (10 мб)

Tags: php, nginx

Все добрый день! Бьюсь несколько дней над решением проблемы 502 bad gateway nginx когда загружаю тяжелые файлы (10 мб). Файлы до 5 мб загружаются без ошибок. Пробовал менять настройки PHP и Nginx, но не помогло. Конфигурация системы: Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx, PHP. В логах Nginx дана следующая информации об ошибке:

```
*17 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 109.252.90.170, server: мой_сайт.ru,
request$ equest: "POST /sources/preview HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "мой_сайт.ru", referrer: "https://мой_сайт.ru/"
```

Настройки PHP:

```
max_input_time = 600;
max_execution_time = 600;
pload_max_filesize = 100M;
post_max_size = 100M;
memory_limit = 256M;
```

Настройки Nginx:

```
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
client_max_body_size 100M;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
client_header_buffer_size 2k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 6m;
fastcgi_send_timeout 6m;
fastcgi_read_timeout 6m;
proxy_connect_timeout       6m;
proxy_send_timeout          6m;
proxy_read_timeout          6m;
send_timeout                6m;
client_header_timeout 6m;
client_body_timeout 6m;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
```

Пробовал создавать файл /etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/30-user.ini, где указал настройки:

```
max_input_time = 600;
max_execution_time = 600;
pload_max_filesize = 100M;
post_max_size = 100M;
memory_limit = 256M;
```

Через phpinfo() проверил что все настройки используются

Что я упустил?

Comment: Вообще нужен лог php-fpm, nginx всего лишь сообщает что оттуда ничего не пришло. [Тут куча возможных вариантов](https://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon). Начните с лога php-fpm

Comment: В логах php-frm вижу следующее [05-Aug-2018 12:50:40] WARNING: [pool www] child 25173 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 30.296949 seconds from start

Comment: Это уже что-то. 30 секунд... покажите `var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time')); die;` в том скрипте, который грузит файлы.

Comment: Показывает `string(3) "600"`

Comment: а что можно делать 30 секунд? этот файл еще и обрабатывается, типа XML? смотрите потребление памяти

Comment: ты прав! :-)))) загружается файл Excel, потом unzip'ом распаковывается и далее парсится. Попробовал убрать эту операцию и все загружается успешно! Сервер 512 мб оперативки, почему не хватает на относительно маленький файл?

Comment: Смотря какой библиотекой парсить. Если PHP_Excel, она кушает много. Включите логи на максимум и смотрите. Может куча объектов отъедает. Это нужно профилировать.

Comment: [Как уменьшить потребление PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817651/phpexcel-runs-out-of-256-512-and-also-1024mb-of-ram)

Comment: Я использую Simple XML, которая гораздо легче PHPExcel. Понял где проблема, решение найду. Спасибо за помощь!!!!

Comment: Используйте XHProf. Он покажет где больше всего расходов по памяти и по скорости. И еще есть потоковый XML читальщик XMLReader, но с ним работать менее удобно.

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю обязательно!